# Find if a Java button is clickable or not using QTP

Tags: button, click, qtp, hp-uft

I am new to QTP and trying out some Java GUI automation. I have to click a java button and sometimes the button may not be available to click. i.e it will be in disable state.

Because of this, my code is fail to click the button

```
JavaWindow("TestApp").JavaButton("Apply").Click
```

How can I make it to handle the error case ?

Note : I am using QTP's record and playback option only, not the descriptive programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check run-time properties of objects using the GetROProperty method.  Check the QTP/UFT help documentation for all the options.  In this case, you could try this:

```
Dim isButtonEnabled
isButtonEnabled = JavaWindow("TestApp").JavaButton("Apply").GetROProperty("enabled")
If isButtonEnabled Then
    JavaWindow("TestApp").JavaButton("Apply").Click
Else
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Button Click", "The button is disabled"
End If
```